# Square full/Powerful numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A positive integer $n$ is called square-full or powerfull if $p^2|n$ for every factor $p$ of $n$ for every prime factor $p$.

I need to show that if $n$ is square-full show so it can be written in the form $n=a^2b^3$ for $a,b$ positive integer.

I looked in wikipedia but the proof was too complicated... is there any easy way to prove this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $p^r$ be the exact power of $p$ dividing $n$. By hypothesis $r\geq2$.

If $r$ is even put $p^r$ under the '$A$' label. If $r$ is odd then $r\geq3$ so you can put $p^3$ under the '$B$' label and $p^{r-3}$ under the '$A$' label.

Do the above for all $p$ dividing $n$. When you are finished you have that $B$ is a product of cubes, thus itself a cube $B=b^3$, and $A$ is a product of primes with even exponents, thus a square $A=a^2$.

Obviously, $n=AB=a^2b^3$.

Comment: I still don't get it. If n is square full number. Doesn't that mean all of its factors have 2 as exponent?  Where did the cubes come from? Like: 36= 2^2 x 3^2  how you factor out primes that have cubes as exponents (except 1 of course)

Comment: @Asim: you need to answer this question: is $8=2^3$ a powerful number? If your answer is yes, then you see the cube. If your answer is no, then you have not understood the definition of powerful number.

Comment: @Asim: and of course $36=6^2\cdot1^3$.

Comment: yes now i know what is powerful number. First i was mistaken and thought that its just number with all factors squared.

Answer (score 3):

Take all the primes $p_{\text{odd}}$ which divide $n$ an odd number of times (at least three each).  Then let $$b= \prod p_{\text{odd}}$$ and $$a = \sqrt{\frac{n}{b^3}}.$$

All you need to show is that $a$ is a positive integer, as $b$ is by definition (noting that the empty product is $1$).  Do this by looking first at primes which divide $n$ an odd number of times (at least three each so when you subtract $3$ you are left with a non-negative even exponent), and then at primes which divide $n$ an even number of times.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $m \geq 2$ is an integer. Then $m = 2\alpha + 3\beta$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are nonnegative integers. The claim follows from this fact, because for any prime $p$ dividing a square-full number $n$, the power of $p$ in the prime factorization of $n$ is $\geq 2$.